# Approximation of weighted sum (sum of a product)

Tags: linear-algebra, approximation, products

(This is my first question here, so I hope my question and phrasing is appropriate.)

Consider $X_i$ and $a_i$. They are real scalars, and they are independent random variables (picked from a finite distribution, for example a Gaussian distribution). When taking the ensemble average $\langle ... \rangle_{\text{ens. avg.}}$ over multiple sets of $[a_1, ..., a_N]$ and $[X_1, ..., X_N]$, is it true that the approximation below holds and that for an infinite number of averages in the ensemble the equation becomes exact?

$$\langle \sum_i^N(a_i\cdot X_i) \rangle_{\text{ens. avg.}} \stackrel{?}{\approx} \langle \text{mean}(a_i) \sum_i X_i \rangle_{\text{ens. avg.}} = \langle(\frac{\sum_i^N a_i}{N}) \cdot \sum_i X_i\rangle_{\text{ens. avg.}}$$

I arrived at this, considering the case where $a_i = a = const.$ for all $i$. In that case the equation $\sum_i^N(a\cdot X_i) = a\cdot X_1 + a\cdot X_2 + a\cdot X_3 + ... = a\cdot(X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + ...) = a \sum_i X_i$ holds due to distributivity of scalar multiplication. So it seems, that for finite distributions of $a_i$, it should be possible to take the mean value of $a_i$ out of the sum. I also ran some numerical tests, indicating that this should be possible. However, I was unable to find a good source for this approximation.

- Can someone verify or refute that this is a valid approximation?
- Does someone have a good reference (i.e. a book or a paper) to why the approximation holds/is wrong?

Thanks for the help!

P.S. The code I used to numerically check this (matlab). As an example I am using two normal distributions around 10 with Sigma = 1:

```
EnsembleAverages = 10000;
Error = zeros(1,EnsembleAverages);

for i = 1:EnsembleAverages
    N = 100;
    X = random('Normal',10,1,1,N);
    a = random('Normal',10,1,1,N);

    Real = sum(a.*X);
    Approx = mean(a)*sum(X);
    Error(i) = (Real-Approx)/Real;
end

MeanError = abs(mean(Error));
```

This yields a MeanError = 0.00015313 %. For larger ensemble averages the MeanError approaches zero.

Comment: If $a_i$'s are random variables, the resulting sum is also a random variable. I am not quite sure what you mean by saying it is approximately equal to something. Typically it is possible to comment on the expected value of the sum or give tail bounds saying $\Pr\left( \sum_{i} a_i X_i \geq t \right) \leq \f(t)$ where $f(t)$ is a decreasing function in $t$.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Thanks for your comment :-) I tried to update the question accordingly. I hope it is more clear now.